# Does the Chinese chess (xiangqi) board at Beijing's 东四 subway station have any significance?

Tags: identify-this, xiangqi

There's a 象棋 board on one of the platforms of Beijing's [东四 subway station](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%9C%E5%9B%9B%E7%AB%99); I took some photos of it:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I tried my best to get decent photos of it, but it's hard to get the angle right, and there's lots of people at the subway.  Wikipedia has this photo:

> [image]

I'm wondering if this position is of any significance.

**Question**: Does the Chinese chess (xiangqi) board at Beijing's 东四 subway station have any significance?

The [Beijing subway website](https://www.bjsubway.com/station/xltwhq/line5/ds/1.html) says:

> 《象棋残局》
> 采用中国象棋的残局进行地面铺装，通过不同颜色的大理石铺设了一盘超大的象棋棋盘，从一个侧面表现了老北京人的市井文化生活。
>
> The Endgame of XiangQi
> By paving the ground in the patterns of Chinese chess endgame, a large Chinese chess board is laid through marbles of different colors to symbolize the cultural life of the Beijingers.

This doesn't help me identify the position.  E.g. maybe it's from some famous game, or arose between famous players.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts for putting this great information in this platform. Will wait for incoming answers..

Comment: The position is very unusual. I'd be surprised if it's from some famous game.